# Parsing CDATA in PHP with DOMDocument

Tags: php, xml, cdata

I have a PHP function (written by a stackoverflow member) that is supposed to write values into an XML file.  One of the elements of the XML needs to be contained in a CDATA.  Specifically the "description" value.  When I run the PHP code, I get the following error:

> Warning: DOMDocument::createElement() expects parameter 2 to be
>   string, object given in
>   /homepages/46/d412048482/htdocs/create_feed.php on line 23
>
> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to DOMNode::appendChild()
>   must be an instance of DOMNode, null given in
>   /homepages/46/d412048482/htdocs/create_feed.php on line 23

I'm not sure where to go from here.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Full PHP

```
<?php

// Script by Fred Fletcher, Canada.

$title = $_POST['title'];
$description = $_POST['description'];

$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$xml->formatOutput = true;
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xml->load('rss/dakashmere.xml');

$element = $xml->getElementsByTagName('item')->item(0);

$pubDate = $element->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0);
$title = $element->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0);
$description = $element->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0);

$newItem = $xml->createElement('item');

$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('title', $_POST['title']));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('description', $xml->createCDATASection($_POST['description'])));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('pubDate', date("F j, Y, g:i a",time())));;

$xml->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0)->insertBefore($newItem, $element);

$xml->save('rss/dakashmere.xml');

echo "Data has been written.";

?>
```

This is what I want the XML to look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<channel>
  <item>
    <title>Birthday Bash!</title>
    <description><![CDATA[ May 3rd, we will be celebrating Team Cherokee's DJ Unique Birthday Bash at Soho Hookah Bar and Lounge.  The event will be hosted by Prince Po of Organized Confusion and Honey Dipp.  There will be special performances by BITTA Records own Da Kashmere and T Solid.  There will also be guest appearances from VH1's Teeny Barrino and Benzino!<br><br><img src="https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/t1.0-9/10177877_440291492772340_8234232488405005533_n.jpg
" width="50%"> ]]></description>
    <pubDate>Sat, 3 May 2014 09:00:00 -0500</pubDate>
  </item>
</channel>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

createCDATASection() creates an XML cdata node, createElement() or createTextNode() create other node types.

You need to append it to your description element node:

```
$description = $newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('description'));
$description->appendChild($xml->createCDATASection($_POST['description']));
```

Comment: That got rid of the error but now I'm faced with it putting automatic escape characters in the code.  It's outputting this: "Team Cherokee\'s"  and "<img src=\"...>" instead of "Team Cherokee's" and "<img src="...>".  Is there a way for me to tell it to take the actual value and not to put in those escape characters?

Comment: DOM will automatically escape special chars in CDATA section as needed. CDATA does not mean that you do not need any escaping, but less. Your escaping seems to be from magic_quotes_gpc or some generic addslashes. This happens before you add it to the CDATA section. Output the $_POST array and see for yourself.

Comment: Yeah I see where it's doing that.  Is there a way to stop that from happening?  I outputted the POST and you are correct.  The problem is when I load the xml in my feed reader, it doesn't show the picture because of those extra escape characters.

Comment: Magic Quotes is an old deprectated feature of PHP. It was removed in PHP 5.4 and should be disabled. See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure why it's doing it but I added:  $description->appendChild($xml->createCDATASection(stripslashes($_POST['description'])));  and that fixed it.  Thanks for all your help!